# I am a beginner i JavaScript and i can't see why this is showing an error in Brackets in ESLint section

Tags: javascript, eslint

```js
var firstName = 'John';
    console.log(firstName);
```

```
    This is leaves an error saying:
    ERROR: Unexpected console statement.[no-console]  
    ERROR: 'console' is not defined.[no-undef]
```

I have tried restarting the app and rewriting the code but it still shows the same error every time.

Comment: An eslint rule of `no-console` is just telling you to remove the `console.log` statement for productional code.

Comment: Please read the eslint documentation for no-console

Answer (score 2):

These are ESLint errors/warnings, not JavaScript errors/warnings. They refer to the rules listed [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) ([`no-console`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) and [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)).

From `no-console`:

> **Rule Details**
>
> This rule disallows calls to methods of the `console` object.

You're using the `console` object, so ESLint tells you you're breaking that rule.

From `no-undef`:

> **Rule Details**
>
> Any reference to an undeclared variable causes a warning, unless the variable is explicitly mentioned in a `/*global ...*/` comment, or specified in the `globals` key in the configuration file.

The error detail in your question says this is in relation to the `console` variable. I'm surprised that `console` isn't a declared variable in the environment where you're running this as it is in all the usual environments (browsers, Node.js), but there you go, apparently it is.